# How to get non grouped data of last row by datetime with multiple joins?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, mariadb-10.4

There is tickets, they always contain some comments (at least one) and table to conect them. All PKs are numeric but randomized, so, timeline based on DATETIME field of ticket/comment table.

I need to list of tickets (id, author) with all LAST (based on datetime field) comment data (id, date, author, text) and aggregated field (how much comments on ticket).

---

Prepared DB Fiddle is here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PUfo2t4JkEMSA3Skw4sua/1

Raw SQL query here:

```sql
SELECT
    tc.ticket_id        AS ticket_id
    , COUNT(c.id)       AS comment_count
    , MAX(c.created_at) AS last_at
    , c.author_id       AS last_author_id
    , c.text            AS last_text
FROM `ticket_comment` AS tc
JOIN `comment`        AS c  ON c.id = tc.comment_id
GROUP BY tc.ticket_id
ORDER BY last_at DESC
```

---

I've got "ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP" error and i understand why it happens, but have no idea how fix it.

I tried to turn off `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` setting but the result will lead to bad data.

Expected data:

| ticket_id | comment_count | last_at | last_author_id | last_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 974442 | 2 | 2022-01-01 00:55:55 | 22222 | t3c2 |
| 462230 | 2 | 2022-01-01 00:33:33 | 11111 | t1c2 |
| 490694 | 1 | 2022-01-01 00:22:22 | 22222 | t2c1 |

What i've got:

| ticket_id | comment_count | last_at | last_author_id | last_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 974442 | 2 | 2022-01-01 00:55:55 | 11111 | t3c1 |
| 462230 | 2 | 2022-01-01 00:33:33 | 11111 | t1c2 |
| 490694 | 1 | 2022-01-01 00:22:22 | 22222 | t2c1 |

Notice the difference in all fields except `ticket_id` and `last_at` – all wrong.

Comment: which version of mysql u use

Comment: @RahulBiswas mariadb 10.4

Comment: please check my query.

Comment: @RahulBiswas did you remove your answer? I was commenting that MAX(id) is not working because they are NOT incremental. So, id 7 can be earlier than id 3.

Comment: my answer is available now. please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subquery for retrieving ticket_id wise comment count and which comments come last based on created date DESC by using ROW_NUMBER().

```
-- MariaDB (10.4)
    SELECT p.ticket_id, p.comment_count
     , p.created_at last_at
     , p.author_id last_author_id
     , p.text last_date
FROM (SELECT *
           , COUNT(c.id) OVER(PARTITION BY ticket_id) comment_count
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id ORDER BY c.created_at DESC) r
      FROM ticket_comment t
      INNER JOIN comment c
              ON c.id = t.comment_id) p
WHERE p.r = 1
ORDER BY p.comment_count DESC
       , p.ticket_id DESC
```

Please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=b461286719332ec3592d40a246ae3bf6

Comment: Thank you for a well explained answer! But, sorry, it’s not working properly.

Comment: please check this answer.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for help! I would never have thought of `OVER`, `PARTITION BY` and `ROW_NUMBER`. Works great, and will research docs for those features.